# Kendo Grid column Calculation

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI AJAX Grid in my ASP.NET MVC project, and I want to calculate the total checked columns. I have 5 Monday to Friday (AM) columns, 5 monday to friday (PM) columns, and two total columns TotalAM and TotalPM. I need TotalAM and TotalPM to be calculated when a user clicks the checkboxes.

For example, if Monday AM and Tuesday AM are checked, then TotalAM should be 2. Similarly, if no PM columns are checked the TotalPM should be 0.

Can you please tell me how to implement this?

```
<%: Html.Kendo().Grid<SSTS.Models.ServiceUseViewModel>()
      .Name("grid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(student => student.StudentNumber).Width(150);
          columns.Bound(student => student.GivenName).Width(150);
          columns.Bound(student => student.FirstDateOfTravel).Width(150);
          columns.Bound(student => student.MondayAM).Width(150);
          columns.Bound(student => student.MondayPM).Width(150);
          columns.Bound(student => student.TuesdayAM).Width(150);
          columns.Bound(student => student.TuesdayPM).Width(150);
          columns.Bound(student => student.WednesdayAM).Width(150);
          columns.Bound(student => student.WednesdayPm).Width(150);
          columns.Bound(student => student.ThursdayAM).Width(150);
          columns.Bound(student => student.ThursdayPM).Width(150);
          columns.Bound(student => student.FridayAM).Width(150);
          columns.Bound(student => student.FridayPM).Width(150);
          columns.Bound(student => student.TotalDaysAM).Width(150);
          columns.Bound(student => student.TotalDaysPM)
                 .Width(150).ClientTemplate("#=calculateField(data)#");
          columns.Bound(student => student.IsMoreThanOnceService).Width(150);  

          columns.Command(commands =>
          {
              commands.Edit(); // The "edit" command will edit and update data items
              commands.Destroy(); // The "destroy" command removes data items
          }).Title("Commands").Width(150);
      })
      .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create()) // The "create" command adds new data items
      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)) // Use inline editing mode
      .DataSource(dataSource =>
          dataSource.Ajax()
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(student => student.StudentNumber); // Specify the property which is the unique identifier of the model
            })
            .Create(create => create.Action("serviceUse_Create", "ServiceUse")) // Action invoked when the user saves a new data item
            .Read(read => read.Action("serviceUse_Read", "ServiceUse"))  // Action invoked when the grid needs data
            .Update(update => update.Action("serviceUse_Update", "ServiceUse"))  // Action invoked when the user saves an updated data item
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("serviceUse_Destroy", "ServiceUse")) // Action invoked when the user removes a data item
      )
     .Pageable().Scrollable()
%>
```

Comment: You could handle click events on the checkboxes themselves.

Comment: can you tell me how or any example/

Comment: In your template, just use kendo's multi-select widget add a handler to the select or change method :: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/multiselect#events-select